# $f$ is a entire function, $f(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathbb{R} , f(\mathbb{iR}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is a entire function, $f(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathbb{R} , f(\mathbb{iR}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, Please prove that $f$ is a even function.

I wanted to consider $f(z)-f(-z)$ and show that it is zero.So I considered the category of singularity $\infty$, but I got no clue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Two applications of Schwarz reflection principle (one for each axis).

Comment: I know how to use it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Robert Israel's answer is probably the easiest approach, but here's another one.  Prove that if $f(\mathbb{R})\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then $f'(\mathbb{R})\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ as well.  Thus by induction on $n$, $f^{(n)}(\mathbb{R})\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  In particular, $f^{(n)}(0)\in\mathbb{R}$, so the coefficients of the Taylor series of $f$ at $0$ are real.  Now apply the same argument to $g(z)=f(iz)$, and use this to show that the odd coefficients of the Taylor series of $f$ must vanish.  Conclude that $f$ is even.